# Form Control by URL Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I have a question about button control and form control. So, I wanted to show data inside field of the form according to the button clicked.

For example:

Button 1 clicked -> show the text field inside the form with text like "you clicked button 1".
Button 2 clicked -> show the text field inside the form with text like "you clicked button 2".

Maybe someone here can give an example.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use jquery and capture the all button click event and get the name of clicked button and set the value to msg text filed like this .

```js
$('button').click(function()
{
   $('#msg').val("you clicked " +$(this).attr('name'));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" >

 msg : <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" >
<button name="button1" id="button1"  >button1</button>
<button name="button2" id="button2" >button2</button>

<span id="msg"> </span>
</form>
```

Comment: The button is placed in different element. You can see it on https://www.domainesia.com/hosting/ and click the "pesan" button, you'll see the different result in the select field inside the form after you click different hosting package of "pesan" button.

Comment: they are just using anchor with GET paramenters <a id="hosting_extra" class="buttonPurchase" href="/pesan&amp;q=hosting&amp;paket=extra&amp;siklus=12/">Pesan</a>

Comment: yes while form rendering they passing parameter to anchor tag